# Delete row from table using custom endpoint via API

Tags: rest-api, endpoints

I would like to delete a row from a table in the database using a custom endpoint via the API. Using an example in the WordPress REST API Handbook, I put together the following code and placed it in my functions.php file:

```
    function delete_custom_row( $id ) {
    global $wpdb;                           

    return $wpdb->delete(
        'xyz_custom_table',         
        ['id' => $id],                  
        ['%d'],                         
    );
} 

    add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
        register_rest_route( 'lic-api/v1', '/deletecustomrow/(?P<id>\d+)', array(
        'methods' => 'POST',
        'callback' => 'delete_custom_row'
        ) );
    } );
```

I know that I have a row in the table with a column 'id' of 3. So when I try to run the code using the endpoint URL of:

```
/wp-json/lic-api/v1/deletecustomrow/3
```

The row is not deleted and I get the following error code:

```
{"code":"rest_no_route","message":"No route was found matching the URL and request method.","data":{"status":404}}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: That's not how parameters are passed to the callback function. Your function is expecting `$id` as a single value, but you need to get the parameters from within the data that's passed to the function. See the example from the docs: https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/#bare-basics

Comment: You should also *always* set a `permission_callback`, particularly in your case where your callback is deleting something from the database. As for the 404 error, try visiting `/wp-json/lic-api/v1` and see if your endpoint is in the list shown on that page - if not, or if that page itself shows a 404 error, then that means your endpoint is not actually registered.

Comment: Thanks @Sally  I did visit  `/wp-json/lic-api/v1`  and it did return my endpoint in the list. So  I know the endpoint is registered.

Comment: Thanks @Jacob. I looked at the example in your link. I am not sure I understand the issue with the parameters. Do you think my function is incorrectly formatted?

Comment: @JohnKeidel In that case, then how did you actually make your REST API request? Did you use custom JS (like `fetch()`) or PHP, and if so, what's your code? Are you aware of the differences between GET and POST requests, and that your endpoint is only accepting POST request? Are you completely certain you used the **POST request method**? Try using cURL - `curl -X POST https://your-domain/wp-json/lic-api/v1/deletecustomrow/3` and confirm if you still get the 404 error?

Comment: As for what Jacob said, basically, you should've used `'id' => $id['id']`. Because the `$id` is actually an instance of the `WP_REST_Request` class and not the `id` value from the request URL or data. See the [Arguments section](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/#arguments) in the REST API handbook for more details.

Comment: Thank you @SallyCJ for your help. When I replaced `['id' => $id]` with `'id' => $id['id']` in the function, as you suggested, I got the following syntax error from the php editor: "unexpected token "=>", expecting ")"".

Comment: @SallyCJ To answer your question as to how I am making my REST API requests, I am using cURL from within an application I am developing. However, I have been testing my endpoints with the browser URL. As you suggested, I did try accessing the endpoint using cURL and the POST request method, and I received the following error from cURL: "HTTP/1.1 406 Not Acceptable, Not Acceptable! An appropriate representation of the requested resource could not be found on this server. This error was generated by Mod_Security."

Comment: "*I got the following syntax error*" - Well, what I meant is, use `$id['id']` instead of just `$id`.. i.e. the full code would be `['id' => $id['id']]` - sorry if I wasn't being clear.. "*However, I have been testing my endpoints with the browser URL.*" - then that means, the request method was GET and *not* POST, hence you got the 404 error. As for the "Not Acceptable" error, that's likely because of the way you were reading the value of the `id` parameter - so try using `$id['id']` instead and see if it helps.

Comment: Thanks @SallyCJ. I modified the function using your code snippet  `['id' => $id['id']]` and tried accessing the endpoint using cURL, but I am getting the same error:  "HTTP/1.1 406 Not Acceptable".

Comment: Sorry, I should've not ignored the "security" part in that 406 error. Anyway, I believe your code is good now, so regarding that 406/Mod_Security-related error, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28090737) or just search for that error on Google. You could also try using another tool to make the request, e.g. Postman, but make sure the HTTP method is POST.

Answer (score 0):

A few things to try... Confirm you are using `POST` and not `GET` when hitting the endpoint. [Postman](https://www.postman.com/) could be helpful here.

It appears you are testing your endpoint using [Pretty Permalinks](https://wordpress.org/support/article/using-permalinks/#pretty-permalinks). Confirm you have Post Name permalink structure setup.
This might be the solution to your problem.

If that works however you are wanting to use [Plain Permalinks](https://wordpress.org/support/article/using-permalinks/#plain-permalinks) format add the `rest_route` query parameter.

Example:
`/wp-json/lic-api/v1/deletecustomrow/3`
becomes
`/?rest_route=/lic-api/v1/deletecustomrow/3`

Comment: Thank you for your help Liam. I tried all of your suggestions, but I am getting the same error returned.

Comment: What PHP and WordPress version are you using? Are you on pretty or plain permalinks? Disable all plugins and try again to confirm there isn't an issue with a third party plugin.

Comment: Thanks @Liam. WordPress version: 6.0.2,  PHP version 8.0.23. My permalinks are set at "Post name". I disabled all plugins, then tried to access my endpoint, but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: How are you testing the post request?